# "Every derived table must have its own alias" Mysql Error

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

Whats wrong with my query:

```
SELECT minDate, deviceType, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT visitorId, deviceType, 
               MIN(sessionDate) as minDate
      FROM sessions
      GROUP BY visitorId)
WHERE minDate > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
GROUP BY minDate, deviceId
```

I've got this message:

> Query Error: Error: ER_DERIVED_MUST_HAVE_ALIAS: Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: "Derived Table" is another name for a subquery, subqueries have to be aliased, as in `SELECT * FROM (SELECT f FROM t) AS q`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is clear enough. You must alias the derived table that is generated by your sub-select. So, give it an alias.

Another issue is that, in the subquery, non-aggregated column `deviceType` should be included in the `GROUP BY` clause. This change might, or might not produce the results that you do expect: if it doesn't, then you would need to provide sample data, expected results and an explanation of what you are trying to accomplish so one can help fixing the query.

```
SELECT minDate, deviceType, COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT visitorId, deviceType, MIN(sessionDate) as minDate
      FROM sessions
      GROUP BY visitorId, deviceType -- all non-aggregated columns in the GROUP BY clause
) t  -- alias here
WHERE minDate > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
GROUP BY minDate, deviceId
```

Comment: thanks, but the error changed to: Query Error: Error: ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP: Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test.sessions.deviceType' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: @GMD any solution?